# OncePerRequestFilter in Jar is not invoking

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, tomcat

I made a simple Jar with spring boot in which I simply placed a single class called IngressFilter whose job is to monitor network calls. Let's call this Jar Network-Tracer for now.

The IngressFilter and Pom.xml code can be found below.

**IngressFilter.Java**

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class IngressFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    IngressFilter() {
        log.info("Started Ingress Filter");
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        log.info("Started network call");
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        log.info("call finished");
    }

}
```

**Pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.6</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.demo.networktracer</groupId>
    <artifactId>network-tracer</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.2</version>
    <name>network-tracer</name>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Nothing special in the code, just a simple jar.

However, when I include this jar as a dependency in one of the spring boot applications, an issue arises.

Assume the application is

- Weather Application

.
Below is the **Pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.6</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.poc</groupId>
    <artifactId>weather</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>weather</name>
    <description>Weather Calling Service</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.demo.networktracer</groupId>
            <artifactId>network-tracer</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

This code initializes when I try to run it. However, when I call one of the weather application's APIs, the Filter isn't called.

I'm also printing logs from the Weather Application for further information.

```
 2022-04-21 07:42:49,128   INFO  [main] org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication: No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
 2022-04-21 07:42:49,761   INFO  [main] org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer: Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
 2022-04-21 07:42:49,765   INFO  [main] org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
 2022-04-21 07:42:49,765   INFO  [main] org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog: Starting service [Tomcat]
 2022-04-21 07:42:49,765   INFO  [main] org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog: Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.60]
 2022-04-21 07:42:49,814   INFO  [main] org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog: Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
 2022-04-21 07:42:49,814   INFO  [main] org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 633 ms
 2022-04-21 07:42:49,976   INFO  [main] org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
 2022-04-21 07:42:49,997   INFO  [main] org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer: Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
 2022-04-21 07:42:50,009   INFO  [main] org.springframework.boot.StartupInfoLogger: Started WeatherApplication in 1.149 seconds (JVM running for 1.605)
```

I looked everywhere on the internet for information on this, but nothing came up.

Please assist me in determining why the network-tracer Ingressfilter is not being invoked.

Comment: You need to set up componentScan for outside packages

Comment: Thank you @Szprota21. It helped. Component scan was missing.